# Use preferred route from OSRM server

Tags: navigation, open-source-routing-machine

I added to an original osm.map my own routes (nodes, ways, relations). I need a way to retrieve from my OSRM server these routes (for navigation).

I try to change the speed of my routes in order to give them a better priority (in lua profile) but the response from OSRM server is a mix of my route and other road.

Is there a way to retrieve (only) my preferred route from OSRM server ?